# Load Delimiter Separated Values in D3

Tags: file, d3.js

I am trying to load a pipe separated value file in D3 using the generic d3.dsvFormat() function.  While I do not get an error, nothing happens which I think is because the callback function is not executed.

I did check the documentation here but did not find it that helpful: https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#dsvFormat

Is there a problem with my syntax?

```
var psv = d3.dsvFormat("|");
psv.parse("my_file.txt", function(error, data) {
    Do a bunch of stuff with the data....
    console.log(data);  //nothing happens here
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`psv.parse` wants text, you are passing text - just that it doesn't have any pipe in it: "my_file.txt". As this is one line of text and the first line of text translates into column names, you won't get any data with this.

Your problem is that `psv.parse` won't fetch a file for you like d3.csv or d3.tsv *(Rather psv.parse() acts like d3.csvParse() or d3.tsvParse())*. Luckily this is not too difficult to fix.

If we look at the API documentation for d3.csv we can recreate the same functionality for any delimited file. With d3.csv,

> If a callback is specified, a GET request is sent, making it
>   equivalent to:
>
> ```
> d3.request(url)
>     .mimeType("text/csv")
>     .response(function(xhr) { return d3.csvParse(xhr.responseText, row); })
>     .get(callback);
> ```

([from API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv))

We just have to emulate this for a pipe separated file:

```
var psv = d3.dsvFormat("|");

d3.request("my_file.txt")
  .mimeType("text/plain")
  .response(function(data) { return psv.parse(data.response) })
  .get(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
```

It's a little bit more verbose than a plain old d3.csv() or d3.tsv(), but achieves the same result with the callback function located in the get method.

*You could also use data.responseText in the response method, I'm not sure what the difference is though, both appear identical in my quick testing.*

*You may have also noted that I did not specify a row function in the response method, this is an optional function that allows "conversion of row objects to a more-specific representation", eg: returning numbers rather than strings. [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv)).*

---

One last note:

In relation to your original code, `psv.parse("text")` returns the data, you don't use a callback function for this method. The following snippet demonstrates how you might parse straight pipe delimited text:

```js
var psv = d3.dsvFormat("|");
var data = psv.parse("a|b\n1|2\n4|3")
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```